# Landing page URL should be redirected to "/home"

Tags: reactjs, url, redirect

Current landing page URL after login - 'www.website.com'. But I want it to be redirected to "www.website.com/home" upon login. So it has to be redirected to home component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simply redirect "/" to "/home"

Comment: I have used <Redirect exact from ="/"  to="/home" />

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just change your path from "/" to "/home"?

Comment: Yeah I can change the path to "\home", but my landing URL cannot recognize "/home" as it would be "www.website.com". How do we redirect to access home component?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a solution to check if the user is log you can do that

```
<Route exact path="/">
  {loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <LoginPage />}
</Route>
```

If not, you need to redirect to '/home' after login directly after the function of log (in the .then() if you'r loginAction is promise or just after login function).
With React Router v5 : history.push('/home')
With React Router v6 : navigate('/home')
See the doc of React Router if you need more explanation.

Comment: I am using MSAL for Azure AD authentication. May I know where I could use react router above.